# Find the directional derivative of $f_{\vec u}(5,2)$ for the function $xy+y^3$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors

[image]
**Find the directional derivative of $f_{\vec u}(5,2)$ for the function $f(x,y)=xy+y^3$ with $\frac{(3i-4j)}{5}$?**

I got $-\frac{17}{5}$ (as the answer) from the derived formula below.

$  \left(2\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)+\left(5\right)+3\left(2\right)^2\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)$

[Incase the above is not readable here is the problem on symbolab.](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/vector-unit-calculator/%5Cleft(2%5Cright)%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B5%7D%5Cright)%2B%5Cleft(5%5Cright)%2B3%5Cleft(2%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%5Cleft(-%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B5%7D%5Cright))
It is in the form $ai+bj$ where $a=y$ and $b=x+3y^2$, as can be seen in the Symbolab, I already plugged in the $x$ and $y$ values which is how I got to my final answer of $-\frac{17}{5}$.

$a$ and $b$ were found by taking the partial derivative of $x$ and $y$ via Symbolab.

*Obviously my answer was wrong, I am not sure where I went wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directional derivative is obtained by taking the dot product of the gradient with the unit vector in the direction of the vector.

$\hat u= \frac{3}{5}\hat i - \frac{4}{5}\hat j$ is a unit vector

$\nabla U=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\hat i + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\hat j$

$U=xy+y^3$

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=y \implies \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}|_{x=5,y=2}=2$

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}=x+3y^2 \implies \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}|_{x=5,y=2}=5+3(4)=17$

$\nabla U |_{x=5,y=2}=2\hat i+17 \hat j$

$D_u=(2 \times\frac{3}{5})+(17 \times \frac{-4}{5})=\frac{-62}{5}$